# Were there any people who were tracked due to using Voldemort's name aside from HP?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, death-eaters

In "The Deathly Hallows", the Death Eaters were able to track down people who said You-Know-Who's name aloud - they have tracked Harry Potter and co after they escaped the wedding because of Harry's use of "Voldemort".

But were there any other people who were tracked the same way? I don't recall anyone other than Dumbledore and Harry Potter saying the name in the first place, and of course Dumbledore wasn't in the position to say the name by then.

P.S. This is related to my other Q, " [At which point did Death Eaters start being able to track people who say you-know-who's name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/at-which-point-did-death-eaters-start-being-able-to-track-people-who-say-you-kno) "

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was only one more person mentioned in The Deathly Hallows who has triggered the "Taboo" - Kingsley Shacklebolt:

> “but the name’s been jinxed, Harry, that’s how they track people! Using his name breaks protective enchantments, it causes some kind of magical disturbance – it’s how they found us in Tottenham Court Road!”
>
> “Because we used his name?”
>
> “Exactly! You’ve got to give them credit, it makes sense. It was only people who were 
>   serious about standing up to him, like Dumbledore, who even dared use it. Now they’ve 
>   put a Taboo on it, anyone who says it is trackable – quick-and-easy way to find Order 
>   members! They nearly got Kingsley – “
>
> “You’re kidding?”
>
> “Yeah, a bunch of Death Eaters cornered him, Bill said but he fought his way out. He’s 
>   on the run now just like us.”
>
> (Above from *"The Deathly Hallows", Chapter Eighteen - "The Life and Lies of Albus Dumbledore"*); after Ron re-joins Harry and Hermione and notices they stopped using Voldemort's name.

---

HP Wikia also mentions that Dean Thomas and Griphook may have been captured by Snatchers the same way, but I can't find any confirmation of that in the book.

Answer (score 1):

### Hermione triggered the Taboo in Tottenham Court Road, not Harry

> After a minute or two, Ron said, “You know, we’re not far from the
> Leaky Cauldron here, it’s only in Charing Cross –
>
> “ “Ron, we can’t!”
> said Hermione at once.
>
> “Not to stay there, but to find out what’s
> going on!”
>
> “We know what’s going on! **Voldemort**’s taken over the
> Ministry, what else do we need to know?”
>
> “Okay, okay, it was just an
> idea!”
>
> <sub>-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

This was a back-and-forth conversation between Ron and Hermione, where Hermione says Voldemort's name, triggering the Taboo. Other than that, Harry
and Kingsley had also triggered it, as shown by DVK-on-Ahch-To's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes - Greyback said a few Order members were tracked that way.

Harry wasn’t the only one who was tracked because he used the Dark Lord’s name - Greyback said that since his name had been Tabooed, they’d tracked a few Order members that way, though Greyback doesn’t specify which Order members those were by name.

> “You know who used to like using the Dark Lord’s name, Weasley?’ growled Greyback. ‘The Order of the Phoenix. Mean anything to you?’
>
> ‘Doh.’
>
> ‘Well, they don’t show the Dark Lord proper respect, so the name’s been Tabooed. A few Order members have been tracked that way.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*</sup></sub>

While it’s possible that Greyback is exaggerating to make their methods seem more effective, Bill Weasley mentions that the Death Eaters almost captured Kingsley Shacklebolt because he used the Dark Lord’s name, so it’s likely Greyback’s statement is based in fact and there are others.