# Why no taboo for the "Dark Lord" to catch Death Eaters?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

We know that Death Eaters call Voldemort "The Dark Lord" (Harry confronting Snape in one the occlumency lessons, *Order of the Phoenix*).

In the seventh book, the Death Eaters jinx the name "Voldemort" to trace the ones who dare to use it, because the ones who use the name are people who are not afraid of Voldemort, like Harry or Dumbledore. I personally think they could do that after gaining power at the Ministry. The Ministry already has a tracing mechanism to catch people who use magic under 17 so they can modify it.* 
[At which point did Death Eaters start being able to track people who say you-know-who's name?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8275/at-which-point-did-death-eaters-start-being-able-to-track-people-who-say-you-kno)

**So the Question is**: after the mass breakout from Azkaban in *Prisoner of Azkaban* couldn't the Ministry of Magic use the same magic to trace Death Eaters like Bellatrix by jinxing the phrase "The Dark Lord"? I know that they didn't believe that Voldemort would be back, but still, Death Eaters escaped from Azkaban.

*Even though Voldemort himself did the Taboo magic, Dumbledore would knew the spell.

I haven't read the books in their original language so I don't know when "The Dark Lord" or "Dark Lord" was used, please consider them as they have the same meaning (I know they don't) and consider the one with the narrower meaning (the one that is used to define specifically Voldemort).

Comment: the ministry is stupid, and jkr has no plot consistancy

Comment: Because it would have resulted in hundreds of false-positives. The term "The Dark Lord" is used by loads of non-Death Eater characters; Dobby, a singing Dwarf, Percy Weasley, Ernie Prang, Professor Trelawney, Harry Potter, Barty Crouch Sr, Karkaroff, Moody, Snape, Malfoy Jr, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum Good Point but for a department(_Aurors_) whose only job is to catch bad wizards that's an effort they can handle . Also Dobby , Trelawney and Harry are all in Hogwarts so they can be sorted out as false positives, but for example the meeting in Malfoy's Mansion or other unknown places will draw attention

Comment: Anytime someone says "It's dark, lord oh lordy." Another false positive. Or when talking to another non-evil master, "Lizzie has been tanning a lot and is getting really dark, lord."

Comment: Because Voldemort is not only the so-called "Dark Lord", it can also be someone outside Hogwarts.

Comment: @Valorum If false positives were a reason to not do something, nobody would ever use anti-virus software. Also it shouldn't be too much of an issue to slowly build a whitelist (e.g. Dobby says "The Dark Lord", Dobby is investigated, Dobby is not a deatheater, Dobby is whitelisted).

Comment: @Pharap - If your AV kicked up a warning every time it encountered the word "virus", you'd uninstall it within a day.

Comment: Because normal wizards are scared to say "Voldemort", now even more so that he has returned. Only the OOTP members & people who want to actively fight his oppression is using "Voldemort". OOTP jinxing "Dark Lord" would serve no purpose because there isnt one phrase which only the Death Eaters use exclusively

Comment: @iMerchant: nah, spells are better than that. For example, wizards in Discworld can safely say "ate", despite that it sounds exactly like the word they're never allowed to say.

Comment: @Pharap Investigating Dobby is the best thing the Ministry can do. He probably learned the phrase from his ex-masters (Malfoys) who turn up to be... guess what... Death Eaters.

Comment: Something tells me Dumbledore would never agree to perform that spell. Besides, the Taboo on "Voldemort" serves a greater purpose than surveillance - after all, it's easily thwarted by just changing the phrase. It's a fear tactic, an Orwellian style removal of a concept, and while the Ministry is definitely corrupt, it's not actively a dictatorship.

Comment: Think of all the Muggles that would be caught as false positives talking about Tolkien, TvTropes, various other works of fiction, singing along with Led Zeppelin or various other bands who have used fantasy motifs in their songs, etc.

Comment: Rather than jinxing the phrase "The Dark Lord", why didn't the Order and its allies use the jinx on "Voldemort" to bring Death Eaters to them (the Order members) at a time and place of the Order's choosing, so that the Death Eaters could be captured or otherwise neutralized?

Comment: @eipi10 Because only Crouch Jr called him Voldemort perhaps? It would have done exactly nothing because only a few people called him Voldemort and it wasn't his Death Eaters. And it's not that it brings them there but makes them trackable. The only people it would have made trackable are - well Harry, Dumbledore and eventually Hermione. Perhaps a few others but not anyone who was alive still that was on Voldemort's side.

Comment: @eipi10 That same idea but executed differently, is actually interesting though. They could've gathered in numbers, and then one of them would've said "Voldemort" and they would "welcome" any Death Eaters arriving. That does remove protective spells, but if they set them up afterwards, or don't rely on them in first place... To be fair, there's a decent chance they'd quickly end up outnumbered, though.

Comment: @EgorHans what if the dark lord himself shows up for the party :)  That would quickly decrease the number of Aurors and member of the order.

Comment: Another fair point. I know it would be quite risky. I guess a bit of speculation is OK in the comments.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two very good reasons why this plan wouldn't work

### False positives.

Within the novels we see loads of characters who aren't Death Eaters using the term "The Dark Lord". If we widen that to just "Dark Lord", that number goes up even higher. Dobby, Harry Potter, Moody, Ernie Prang, Barty Crouch Sr and even a singing dwarf Valentine all use the expression. If the Auror Dept was charged with investigating all of these, they'd be run ragged. The term is simply too widespread to be used as a useful measure of where Death Eaters are congregating

### The wizarding world isn't a fascist dictatorship

The reason the whole "*Voldemort's name is taboo*" thing works is because the Death Eaters took the time to take over the reins of power and establish a climate of fear in which they can operate freely. If the Auror Dept was to use the same techniques (surprise apparation, snatcher squads, kidnapping and torture) they'd soon find themselves facing a rebellion.

Comment: They are not fascist dictators but they do not hesitate to send more than 100 hundred soul eating creatures to a school of teenagers to catch one criminal in PoA. But this will be the correct answer probably if nothing more satisfying comes

Comment: If you look closely, the whole wizarding world we see (in other words, England) is a horribly run facist dictatorship. Think along the lines of North Korea, and then it becomes Nazi Germany under Voldemort.

Comment: Widening it to just "Dark Lord" is a messure which is just stupid. I mean, in what sentence you would say "Dark Lord" without "The" when you talk about a 3rd person whos the only of his kind? omiting the "The" is not even worth mentioning in my opinion.

Comment: "The wizarding world isn't a fascist dictatorship" - Uhhhh, the wizarding world is one with a whole bunch of invasion of privacy, little to no due process that gets easily bent, flimsy evidence-gathering to sentence someone for crimes often without even a trial, no real sentencing option beyond Azkaban, sentences all criminals to torture, no real checks and balances on the government, and operate as a superpower with blatant disregard for "inferiors/beasts" and nationalistic/superiority-based ideology. "Fascist Dictatorship" is basically the only accurate way to describe the wizarding world.

Comment: @Zaibis - The words "Dark Lord" (with the "The") appear several times in the text

Comment: You mean ""Dark Lord" (with [out] the "The")"? Can you give me an example? I really can't think of the circumstances where it amkes sense.

Comment: @Zaibis - "*That’s probably why You Know Who wanted to kill him in the first place. Didn’t want **another Dark Lord** competing with him. I wonder what other powers Potter’s been hiding?’*" said Ernie Prang...

Comment: Well thats a case where there is spoken of him in a way not expecting him to be the only of his kind. Also I can't remember that Ernie Prang had been a death eater and also can't really imagine. Note that non deatheaters omitng the "The" just again support my claim, as this even proves it would reduce false positives.

Comment: @Zaibis - Either way, the term is spoken by literally dozens of non-Death-Eaters throughout the book series. False positives would kill this idea dead, even if you could get public support for Aurors popping in every time you said it.

Comment: @GreySage The UK, thank you very much. The vast majority of the books take place in Scotland ;)

Comment: @Valorum: Sorry, I don't get what you are telling me about it yet. I just asked for a quote where a death eater is saying "Dark Lord" without a "The". Because I can't think of a sentence where this occurs in a way it would be still attributing respect and obedience, as it is expected from deatheaters. Ofcourse you can say something a long the lines "pffff 'dark Lord' I don't care about[...]"  Or "'Dark Lord' thats the name we gave him as hes the only one by his superity" the former never would be said by a true death eater while the second for sure might be. [cont]

Comment: ... But the point is both is they are descriptive and not a direct matter about the person but more about the name and for sure not directly addressing him. And that would just almost anytime result in false positives. And therefor I asked why one would even consider omiting the "The"?

Comment: @Zaibis - *"Oh Dark Lord, forgive me"*?

Comment: @Valorum: My initial comment said "when you talk about a 3rd person whos the only of his kind" so here it isn't the 3rd person anymore. I was thinking of that one too. This point is indeed a positive. But this is just taking place when ever some one directly talks to him, what just made me initially thinking in having no gain from omiting the "the". You had 2 options. far the more commonly: The aurors pop in when ever someone just describes him or prays to him in some way. Or after years of false positives a few aurors unprepared just pop in on a meeting of the lord and his closest.

Comment: And as I'd assume both cases aren't what one would want to achieve. So omiting the "The" isn't a good idea. Why you can't just accept that? xD

Comment: @zaibis - What you're describing sounds like an excellent way for Death Eaters to ambush aurors.

Comment: @zaibis - I've made reference to both "The Dark Lord" and "Dark Lord" **because that's what's in the question**.

Comment: @Valorum: Well he jsut mentioned it after the edit 4 hours ago. But you are right, for that reason now that part is correct too. +1 For answering even parts not beeing asked at that time ^^

Comment: Because if you did I'll pay actors to read allowed passages from the Lord of the Rings until you're fed up chasing bad leads.

Comment: @Joshua As I recall, that's basically the solution used in the Belgariad: to stop the Big Bad from magically listening in to conversations about him, they persuade the monarchs to 'suggest' that storytellers around the country begin telling old tales about the last time he was defeated...